Apple Mail on macOS: Possible to add padding to message pane? The message has literally 0 padding when it's text only
One of the most frustrated things when I switched to Mail.app on macOS is that I noticed that when you receive a text-only email there is zero padding in the message pane, so the text is literally touching the pane that shows the lists of messages.
The designer in me is driven mad by this. I am using the latest macOS Sonoma 14.4.1. Mail.app version 16.0.
Is there anyway to fix this problem? You can see it here:

